# Bundled/Grouped notifications in Android Oreo showing seperate notifications for same group

Tags: android, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to get the bundled/grouped notifications working and so far it keeps on showing me 2 separate notifications, here's the code that I'm using:

```
final int notificationId = 1;
final String channelId = "my_channel_id_01";
final String groupKey = "my_group_id_01";

// The user-visible name of the channel.
final String channelName = "My Testing Channel";

// The user-visible description of the channel.
final String channelDesc = "Just testing a channel";

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationChannel mChannel = null;

//define the channel
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
    mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

    // Configure the notification channel.
    mChannel.setDescription(channelDesc);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);

    // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
    // channel, if the device supports this feature.
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

    if (mNotificationManager != null)
    {
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
}

//large icon
Bitmap largeIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

//notification builder
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setLargeIcon(largeIconBitmap)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setGroupSummary(true)
.setGroup(groupKey)

//when collapsed
.setContentTitle("Default notification")
.setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
.setContentInfo("Info")

//when expanded
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
        .setBigContentTitle("Content Text")
        .setSummaryText("Summary text") //summary text
        .addLine("Some text 1")
        .addLine("Some text 2")
        .addLine("Some text 3")
        .addLine("Some text 4")
        .addLine("Some text 5"));

//set category
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    notificationBuilder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SOCIAL);
}

//notify user
if (mNotificationManager != null)
{
    //1st notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());

    //2nd notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId + 1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using API v26 with Android Oreo emulator image (v26 as well). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any update on the solution?

Comment: any update @Sdghasemi?